# Flawed proof that the closure of a set is closed?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

So I'm reading baby Rudin's third edition and on page 35, he shows a proof that the closure of a set is closed. (I'm not questioning the result, but it seems to me the proof has a mistake and I'm curious if others agree with my statement)

Let $X$ be a metric space with the usual topology and $E \subset X$. Now $E'$ is the set of all limit points of $E$. So we want to prove that $C = E' \cup E$ is closed.

So here is the provided proof:
If $p \in X$ and $p \notin C$ then $p$ is neither a point of $E$ nor a limit point of $E$. Hence $p$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$. The complement of $C$ is therefore open. Hence $C$ is closed.

The problem I have with the above proof is this: What if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point of $E'$ but not $E$? I see no statement in the proof which would exclude this possibility. Then the complement of $C$ is not open and so $C$ is not closed. In other words, the proof seems to be based on the assumption that $(E^c)^c=C$ which is not necessarily true.

Again, to clarify, I'm not claiming the above is possible. I'm just trying to understand if my objection to the proof (not the theorem) is correct.

Comment: Choose the neighbourhood open. (I believe Rudin defines neighbourhoods to be open, so then this would be pleonastic.) Call it $U$, and name the point of $E'$ in $U$ $q$. Then $U$ is a neighbourhood of $q$, and by definition of limit points, $U$ contains a point in $E$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The situation that you envision cannot occur. Suppose that $U$ is an open nbhd of $p$ that contains a point $x\in E'$. Then $U$ is an open nbhd of $x$. And $x$ is a limit point of $E$, so every open nbhd of $x$ contains points of $E$, and in particular $U\cap E\ne\varnothing$.

Rudin’s statement that if $p\notin C$, then $p$ has a nbhd that does not intersect $E$ is therefore correct; you just have to fill in a couple of details to verify its correctness.

Comment: Trying out the new word I just learned in Daniel Fischer's comment above: the statement "you just have to fill in a couple of details to verify its correctness" is **pleonastic** when applied to any proof in Rudin :-)

Comment: @Bungo: It’s not *quite* that bad, but Walter certainly did make a good stab at maximum compression and efficiency of exposition! Mary Ellen was usually easier to read, even in her papers, though it often turned out later that she’d done things the hard way.

Comment: As someone using it for self-study, I really appreciate the high information density. But the non-sequitures in some proofs occasionally make me lose time because I can't always tell the difference between an omitted step and a failure on my part to understand the argument.

Answer (score 0):

Rudin is reported to have written "Hence $p$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$."

What appears to be needed is that $p$ has a neighborhood that does not intersect $E\cap E'$.

It seems to me Rudin ought to have said that.

The contemplated possibility is that some neighborhood of $p$ intersects $E'$ although it does not intersect $E$.

If some point $x\in E'$ is in an open neighborhood $G$ of $p$, then one can show that some point of $E$ is in $G$, as follows.  Since $G$ is open and $x\in G$, some open ball $B$ centered at $x$ is a subset of $G$.  That open ball must intersect $E$ since $x\in E'$ (so all open balls centered at $x$ intersect $E$).  Every point in the intersection of $B$ with $E$ is a member of $G$ since $B\subseteq G$.